# Calculating odds to succeed in N trials with changing success rate and a maximum success rate.

Tags: probability

Let me preface this by saying that this is similar to the following question: [Calculating Probability with Changing Odds.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3235799/calculating-probability-of-success-with-changing-odds) However I do have some differences in the problem that I am having trouble figuring out.

The problem is:

> Imagine you have the chance at succeeding at some task with a base rate of $R$. Everytime you fail to succeed, the possible success rate increases by $10\%$. That is the new success rate for the next try will be $R + (R * 0.10)$ This relation holds true until a maximum success rate of $2R$. How do you calculate the average amount of tries to succeed? And how do you calculate the probability that you will fail $N$ number of times before succeeding?
>
> So for example if our $R = 10\%$ then it will increase by $1\%$ each time, upto a maximum success rate of $20\%$.

I'm having a bit of trouble modifying the solution from the linked problem to account for this constraint of a maximum success rate. Could anyone provide me a method on how to calculate the average attempts and probability of failing $N$ trials?

Comment: You mean somerhing like this [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=0.5%5E%28k-1%29*0.5*0.45%5E%28m-1%29*0.55)?  There is $R=0.5$ and two successes.

Comment: @callculus42 Maybe? I'm having a bit of trouble deciphering how that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\ r\ $ is the fraction by which $\ R\ $ increases after each failure, then the probability $\ R_n\ $ of success in the next trial after $\ n\ $ failures is given by
$$
R_n=\min\big( (1+r)^nR, 2R\big)\ ,
$$
—that is, $\ R_n=(1+r)^nR\ $ if $\ n\le\left\lfloor\frac{\log(2)}{\log(1+r)}\right\rfloor\ $, or $\ R_n=2R\ $ otherwise. The probability of success after after exactly $\ N\ $ failures is therefore
$$
(1+r)^NR\prod_{n=0}^N\big(1-(1+r)^nR\big)
$$
if $\ N\le d=\left\lfloor\frac{\log(2)}{\log(1+r)}\right\rfloor\ $, or
$$
2R\left((1-2R)^{N-d}\prod_{n=0}^d\big(1-(1+r)^nR\big)\right)
$$
if $\ N>d\ $.

The expected number of failures occurring before success is terefore
\begin{align}
\sum_{N=1}^dN(1+r)^NR&\prod_{n=0}^N\big(1-(1+r)^nR\big)\\
&\hspace{2em}+2R\prod_{n=0}^d\big(1-(1+r)^nR\big)\sum_{N=d+1}^\infty N(1-2R)^{N-d}\\
&=\sum_{N=1}^dN(1+r)^NR\prod_{n=0}^N\big(1-(1+r)^nR\big)\\
&\hspace{1em}+2R\prod_{n=0}^d\big(1-(1+r)^nR\big)\sum_{m=1}^\infty (m+d)(1-2R)^m\\
&=\sum_{N=1}^dN(1+r)^NR\prod_{n=0}^N\big(1-(1+r)^nR\big)\\
&\hspace{3em}+(1+2Rd)\prod_{n=0}^d\big(1-(1+r)^nR\big)\ ,
\end{align}
and the expected number of attempts to success will be one more than this.